# Saltar firewall con transferencia de archivos al usar XMPP

Tags: xmpp

Tengo una cuestión sobre el protocolo XMPP. Mi pregunta es como se puede hacer por ejemplo en mi chat para transferir archivos sin que el firewall me bloquee ya que la mayoría de casos no me deja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas compañero, lo primero que debes de revisar es los puertos, según lo que encontré en un [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452161/which-ports-does-xmpp-use) de StackOverflow en inglés debes conciderar los siguientes puertos:

```
5222 TCP     XMPP client connection (RFC 3920)        Official  
5223 TCP     XMPP client connection over SSL          Unofficial
5269 TCP     XMPP server connection (RFC 3920)        Official
5298 TCP UDP XMPP JEP-0174: Link-Local Messaging /    Official
             XEP-0174: Serverless Messaging
8010 TCP     XMPP File transfers                      Unofficial
```

La comunicación ocurre normalmente sobre conexión TCP en el **Puerto** **5222** en el caso cliente-servidor y en el **Puerto 5269**, además del **Puerto 2523** para SSL en el caso de servidor-servidor, como se lee en las [concideraciones de IANA](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#iana).

Ahora bien, lo que debes hacer es buscar la manera de desbloquear puertos. Sí es por el Firewall de Windows [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNQ3ajl6Rho) te dejo un video de como abrir los puertos, sí es por un firewall de algún antivirus o en caso de un firewall físico, ahí si debes buscar específicamente como hacerlo. Espero te sirva esta ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En Openfire, servidor XMPP escrito en Java, puedes transferir archivos via proxy, por el puerto 7777. Es decir, en este caso debes abrir este puerto. Saludos